# Issue with calculated field for percentage in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

We have a report with 3 charts and 5 filters.

The 3 charts are  :

**Pie chart** : based on cluster name

**Machine count,** which is the distinct count of all serial numbers.

**Percent** : which calculates the percentage of machines in pie chart/ machine count(machine count will remain fixed for cluster name)

In this dashboard the **cluster name filter** is not applied on the machine count worksheet. Rest all filters are applied on all the worksheets in the dashboard.

we have a calculation which is 
calculating the percentage of all the clusters to the total machine count.
The formulas used are

```
numerator : countd(if [cluster name] <> "Not Clustered" 
then 
[Serial No]
END)
```

denominator

```
countd(
[Serial No]
)
```

percent

```
round(([numerator]/[denominator]) * 100,2)
```

Screenshot :

[image: Tableau Image]

So if you refer to the above screenshot, when the filters value is changed for cluster name(say test cluster1) then percentage should be 4/21 = 19% but we are getting percentage as 100 %

So expected value is 19% but we aer getting 100 %
How do we make sure that the machine count should be fixed and calculation is 4/21= 19% in this case.

Workbook attached at this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10LaepEACuZusSt-zgd6X5PoQ_Qf9z8Hn)
* Note : We tried to implement the above using LoD but did not get expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below formula for denominator (we should be fixing the calculation in order to not be effected by our filters):

```
{fixed:SUM(([Number of Records]))}
```

And below for Nominator: (Computed automatically and summarized Table(Accross) )

```
TOTAL(countd(if [cluster name] <> "Not Clustered" 
then [Serial No] END))
```

And you percent field s/b:

```
[numerator]/SUM([denominator])
```

This way, you should be getting the correct percentage values. If not, I may send back the changed .TWBX file.